# Does myBatis implement JPA?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, implementation, mybatis

An easy question I suppose

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. iBatis is not an ORM mapper like Hibernate, so it doesn't implement JPA. JPA isn't even mentioned in official [user guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/list?can=3&q=Docs).

By the way, iBatis is retired. It's been renamed to [myBatis](http://github.com/mybatis/), so you should use that instead.