# Loading Spring context with JPA at runtime and storing in HttpSession

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistence

Usually a web application has a one-to-one mapping of a database account. But in my application I have to ask the database user and password at the very first page that loads. In this case I cannot load Spring with JPA at the time of the application startup. I have to do it once the user successfully provided the database user and password. In other words, Spring and all other frameworks are designed to load everything at application startup, but I don't want to do that.

This application requires each user to specify `userid` and `password`. If the user is authenticated I want to use same database connection for the rest of configuration of Spring and JPA.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have a separate database for each of your users in a webapp?

Comment: You might need to clarify what is JPA/MyBatis in your question first. Refer to this thread for the clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225231/does-mybatis-implement-jpa

Comment: Improved grammar/spelling.